# Layout issue in vote history

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

The new SO design has resulted in a layout issue in the users voting history.  The user's history is presented in a table but if the number of rows in the left and right column don't match, then we get an unusual amount of whitespace presented at the top.

Left column whitespace:

> [image]

Right column whitespace:

> [image]

If the number of rows matches on both sides, the table displays correctly:

> [image]

Can we please have this fixed?  I'm seeing this behavior in Chrome for Mac.

Comment: The tables are being vertically centered in relation to one another... somehow. I cannot find any distinguishing CSS rules that could have caused this.

Comment: @BoltClock Most browsers have a `td, th { vertical-align: middle }` in their default style sheets. No one ever remembers to override it until stuff like this happens.

Comment: @animuson: Well that would be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. Thanks!