# Migration Stats page layout bug

Tags: bug, design

The [migration stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) page displays the number of questions migrated to Stack Overflow and away from here.  The data is displayed in table but the stats are displayed incorrectly. Each column is being vertically centered and since we get more posts migrated to Stack Overflow there is a bunch of whitespace in the migrated from column.

> [image]

This is a similar to the issue that was previously fixed on the [vote history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283718/layout-issue-in-vote-history) page.

Can we fix this too?

Comment: It needs fixing for sure. `vertical-align: top` needed. Also, each entry is within a `div` and the alignment on images and stats is off. See here: http://i.imgur.com/GxtqTF9.png this also needs to be fixed.

Comment: @abhitalks I'd rather the page be reworked to not use HTML tables than simply aligning it to the top (though this is a very quick fix)

Comment: @DavidG: Agreed. It is only one table used for columns and can be easily replaced. But it sure does need alignment on entries' icons and statistics text.